# Filestack web picker API not recognising files in iCloud Drive on mobile

Tags: javascript, laravel, icloud-drive, filestack

I am using Filestack in my app to facilitate file uploads.

There is a problem on Apple devices when user try to upload from the Files app.

Files appear greyed out and un-selectable.

I have raised this issue with Filestack who have acknowledged the reproducible bug and have said they will get to it. However that was months ago. I have chased several times.

Clearly, Apple users make up a significant portion of the market and this bug is leading me to lose customers. I am wondering if the Stackoverflow community is aware of this and/or is aware of a workaround?

Here is my code for the Filestack web picker:

```
<script src="//static.filestackapi.com/filestack-js/3.x.x/filestack.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Set up the picker
    const clientOptions = {
        security: {
            policy: "{{$uploadpolicy}}",
            signature: "{{$uploadsignature}}"
        }
    }

    const client = filestack.init("{{env('FILESTACK_KEY')}}", clientOptions);

    const options = {
        storeTo: {
            location: 's3',
            path: '{mypath}'
        },
        uploadConfig: {
            tags: {
                "app": "{myapp}"
            }
        },
        onUploadDone: updateForm,
        maxSize: {{env('PRO_FILESIZE_LIMIT')}} * 1024 * 1024,
        maxFiles: {{env('PRO_TRACK_LIMIT')}},
        accept: 'audio/*',
        uploadInBackground: true,
        transformations: {},

        onFileSelected(file) {
            if (file.size > {{env('PRO_FILESIZE_LIMIT')}} * 1024 * 1024) {
                throw new Error('File too big, select something smaller than 240MB');
            }
        }
    };

    const picker = client.picker(options);


    const form = document.getElementById('pick-form');
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileupload');
    const btn = document.getElementById('picker');
    const nameBox = document.getElementById('nameBox');
    const urlBox = document.getElementById('urlBox');


    btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        picker.open();
    });

    var page = window.location.pathname;

    function updateForm(result) {

        var data = result.filesUploaded;
        console.log(data);
        $.post({
            type: 'POST',

            url: '/uploadtrack/{{$artist_token}}',
            data: {uploads: result.filesUploaded},
            // dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (response) {
                // do stuff
        });

    }


</script>
```

This all works great on any desktop. On iPhone devices when browsing for files, valid file types are greyed out and un-selectable. I would expect them to be selectable.